# having issue when updation Highcharts object using highcharts-ng directive

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

Im facing an issue with highcharts-ng directive when updating some of my hightcharts graphes. When i use this syntaxe charts is updated like charm but didn't seem to show any of my data labels:

```
$scope.chartRonConfig = {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser<br>skjdfhsjdkf<br>2019',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        y: 40
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                distance: -50,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: 'white'
                }
            },
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            center: ['50%', '75%']
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        innerSize: '50%',
        data: [
            ['Firefox', 10.38],
            ['IE', 56.33],
            ['Chrome', 24.03],
            ['Safari', 4.77],
            ['Opera', 0.91],
            {
                name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                y: 0.2,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        ]
    }]
};
```

but when im using this syntaxe:

```
$scope.chartRonConfig = Highcharts.chart('RonContainer', { // same config }
```

nothing is updating.

The view is pretty simple:

```
<highchart id="RonContainer" config="chartRonConfig"></highchart>
```

I don't know what im i missing here. Any help would be appreciated.

THank you.[image]

Comment: with highcharts-ng from memory you can just run update the $scope variables to edit the title you can have a function that when called updates the title e.g. $scope.chartRonConfig.title.text = 'hello world'

Comment: yes but why It's not showing the data labels when I initiate the Chart?!

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo on the jsfiddle.net? It will allow us to debug it. From the images it is really difficult to predict the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your attention, i did solve it with using an early highcharts version instead of using 5.0.12 i use 5.0.11 and it did solve my problem i think it's due to highcharts-ng code that dosn't support the latest version of highcharts.

Thank you.

Regards
Marouan